# Product Reviews showing product page information with page caching using Varnish, APC, and Block Caching

Tags: magento, apc, varnish

I'm seeing some strange behavior on my product pages when trying to view/submit reviews.  The review page has essentially the same information as the product page (just styled a bit funny).

We have applied many caching related performance improvements to Magento.  We are using APC, Varnish with the PageCache extension, Fooman Speedster, and have added the product and category blocks into the Magento cache.

I'm fairly certain I need to do something with one of these caches, but I'm not sure what.  Is it the block caching?  Varnish?

Anyone experienced this and have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way to isolate the issue would be to disable your caches 1 by 1.

Also, a URL might help ...

Comment: We're testing some things now, but here's the problem in action:

http://test.softstarshoes.com/adult-shoes/moccasins/viley-caramel-navy.html

http://test.softstarshoes.com/review/product/list/id/1515/category/71/#review-form